# Closed form for $\sum_{k=a}^b{n \choose k}{k \choose r}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, generating-functions

I know that the following sum ($0 \le a \le b \le n$):

$$\sum_{k=a}^b{n \choose k}{k \choose r}$$

has a closed form when $a = 0$ and $b = n$:

$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}{k \choose r} = 2^{n-r}{n \choose r}$$

(see e.g. [Gould's Table of Combinatorial Identities vol. 2, page 4, (1.21)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171118024544/http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.2.PDF)), but is it possible to simplify it in the other cases?

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+binom+%28n%2Ck%29+*+binom+%28k%2Cr%29+for+k%3Da..b&dataset=) outputs a sum of two terms with hypergeometric functions.

Comment: shouldn't the second sum be from $k=r$ to $n$?

Comment: @joriki, is this allowed: $$\sum_{k=0}^b{n \choose k}{k \choose r}-\sum_{k=0}^a{n \choose k}{k \choose r}=\sum_{k=a}^b{n \choose k}{k \choose r}?$$

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya: Well, almost, you need to substract the sum up to $a-1$, since the term for $k=a$ should remain.

Comment: @Mastrem: It's OK to start at $0$ since the second binomial coefficient is $0$ if the lower index is greater than the upper index.

Comment: @joriki, thank you for correction. Does it simplify the problem?

Comment: @VerkhovtsevaKatya: I'm afraid it doesn't. Wolfram|Alpha still gives a sum of two hypergeometric terms. If you use

$$
\sum_{k=a}^b=\sum_{k=a}^n-\sum_{k=b+1}^n\;,
$$

then at least you only get [a single hypergeometric term](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+binom+%28n%2Ck%29+*+binom+%28k%2Cr%29+for+k%3Da..n). I doubt you'll find anything better than that.

Comment: @Mastrem: How did you derive that? This confirms that there won't be a closed form, since we'd know if there were a closed form for partial sums of binomial coefficients with common upper index.

Comment: @ joriki I made a mistake. What I do have is $\sum_{k=a}^b{n\choose k}{k\choose r}={n\choose r}\sum_{k=a}^b{n-r\choose k-r}$